# java tokens when is long no catch it

Tags: java

hello i am having a problem when trying to catch tokens from a html form , the form have 3 tokens to fill, password, repeatpassword and email the email token are giving me problems, if i fill an email short like 123@hotmail.com it work fine, but if i fill b0rtzito@hotmail.com it dont work and i dont know the reason, i tried with many combinations unssuccessfull, maybe someone can point me , thanks in advance.

```
if (command.startsWith("PasswordCreate2"))
    {
        StringTokenizer create = new StringTokenizer(command, " ");

        String pass = null, repeat = null, email = null;
        create.nextToken();

        if (create.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            pass = create.nextToken();
        }
        if (create.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            repeat = create.nextToken();
        }
        if (create.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            email = create.nextToken();
        }

        if (!((pass == null) || (repeat == null) || (email == null)))
        {
            if (!pass.equals(repeat))
            {
                player.sendMessage("The password doesn't match with the repeated one!");
                NpcHtmlMessage htm = new NpcHtmlMessage(0);
                htm.setHtml(HtmCache.getInstance().getHtm(player.getHtmlPrefix(), htmlPath + "createPassword2.htm"));
                player.sendPacket(htm);
                return false;
            }
            if (pass.length() < 3)
            {
                player.sendMessage("The password is shorter than 3 chars! Please try with a longer one.");
                NpcHtmlMessage htm = new NpcHtmlMessage(0);
                htm.setHtml(HtmCache.getInstance().getHtm(player.getHtmlPrefix(), htmlPath + "createPassword2.htm"));
                player.sendPacket(htm);
                return false;
            }
            if (pass.length() > 30)
            {
                player.sendMessage("The password is longer than 30 chars! Please try with a shorter one.");
                NpcHtmlMessage htm = new NpcHtmlMessage(0);
                htm.setHtml(HtmCache.getInstance().getHtm(player.getHtmlPrefix(), htmlPath + "createPassword2.htm"));
                player.sendPacket(htm);
                return false;
            }

            if (!(email.contains("@") || email.contains(".")))
            {
                player.sendMessage("please fill a valid email record you may need it to recover your account.");
                NpcHtmlMessage htm = new NpcHtmlMessage(0);
                htm.setHtml(HtmCache.getInstance().getHtm(player.getHtmlPrefix(), htmlPath + "createPassword2.htm"));
                player.sendPacket(htm);
                return false;
            }

            PlayerSecondPassword.onCreate2(player, pass, email);
        }
        else
        {
            NpcHtmlMessage htm = new NpcHtmlMessage(0);
            htm.setHtml(HtmCache.getInstance().getHtm(player.getHtmlPrefix(), htmlPath + "createPassword2.htm"));
            player.sendPacket(htm);
            player.sendMessage("Please fill all of the fields before continuing.");
            return false;
        }
```

i always get the return "Please fill all of the fields before continuing"

Comment: Does `email` equal to `null` when you enter a long email?

Comment: I assume your command string is something like
String command="PasswordCreate2a mypass mypass b0rtzito@hotmail.com";
In this case both the emails should work fine. The error you are getting is probably because either pass/repeat/email is coming as null in command string.

Comment: yes equal to null.

Comment: the command sended is that: action="bypass -h PasswordCreate2 $pass $repeat $email"

Comment: Could you add some debug lines and share/check the result:
(before the if clause at the top)beginning of this code pasted here: System.out.println("command "+command);

Comment: ok i will do now , thanks for your help, i really appreciate it.

Comment: it show comand PasswordCreate2 123 123         in the java console, 123 123 are the password filled and above the check if email == null i added another system.out.println("email is" + comand) and it say email is null

Comment: and if i add 123 123 1234@hotmail.com  it show  passwordCreate2 123 123 1234@hotmail.com

Comment: i tested now and seems the problem is when the variable email have more than 4 characters before the @ something weird..omg

Comment: this email work 1234@hotmail.com  this email no 12345@hotmail.com

Comment: Ok. Atleast we seem to have narrowed down the problem... WHen you said the command sent is action="bypass -h PasswordCreate2 $pass $repeat $email. From where are you giving this. The problem seems to be there and not at the java level. The java code is not getting the email value correctly. How is the String command populated ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112976/discussion-between-b0rto-and-crusaderpyro).